# How to move a turtle with keys

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to have a race with these four turtles where each turtle has a different button to move it two pixels forward but i can't get it to work and i was wondering in anyone here could help?

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint
speed(0)
penup()
goto(-140,140)
for step in range(16):
  write(step, align='center')
  right(90)
  forward(10)
  pendown()
  forward(150)
  penup()
  backward(160)
  left(90)
  forward(20)
ada = Turtle()
ada.color('red')
ada.shape("turtle")
ada.penup()
ada.goto(-160, 100)
ada.right(360)
ada.pendown()
bmb = Turtle()
bmb.color('cyan')
bmb.shape("turtle")
bmb.penup()
bmb.goto(-160, 70)
bmb.right(360)
bmb.pendown()
cbc = Turtle()
cbc.color('lawn green')
cbc.shape("turtle")
cbc.penup()
cbc.goto(-160, 40)
cbc.right(360)
cbc.pendown()
dgd = Turtle()
dgd.color('dark violet')
dgd.shape("turtle")
dgd.penup()
dgd.goto(-160, 10)
dgd.right(360)
dgd.pendown()
```

Comment: I don't see any code reading the keyboard here.  Did you not include it?

Comment: You can put your turtle creation in a function, where you pass the color and starting location.  That eliminates the repeated code.

Comment: I'm going to scold you a bit here for not using Google, which is WAY faster than this site.  I Googled "python turtle read keyboard", and the first page contains tutorials and reference guides.

Comment: don't know how to get the code to read the keyboard and i was wondering if you could show me some code doing that. Also i tried onkey and it didn't work. I am using trinket.io if that helps. Thanks! 

Comment: *I tried onkey and it didn't work* -- then you did it wrong.  Show us what you tried and we'll guide you.  Why don't you just install your own copy of Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on the turtle library itself for this. For example with the `onkey` function. Just as an example:

```
from turtle import *

def up():
    # ...handle...

onkey(up, 'Up')
```

You can find much more about this [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-turtle-graphics-keyboard-commands/)